# If root partion is shrinked, what system will boot up. if not then why?

Tags: linux

I have 20 GB of /root partion and I want to reduce up to 10 GB but fear of would system boot again? kindly ans the query if yes then why , if no then why ?

Comment: As long as you still have enough space it'll boot but 10GB is very small nowadays.

Comment: Is you meen root (as in /) yoy should be fine, but there is an element of risk of corruption of the boot procrss. Nit sure why, but ive seen it 1 time in 20 resizes.. If you di mean the path "/root" there is no risk of not booting as this path is just user storage and not used by the boot process.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't change the UUID of the partition and only shrink it, this should be no problem if you have an ext partition.